Data Visualization -Incorrect Data
I have a CSV file with data that I'm trying to compile into some type of graph. I managed to get one beautiful heatmap thanks to Google Colab's "recommended plots" generator, but all other ideas I've had are not turning out properly.
Here's an example of my dataset:
    ACCT    DIV     SOURCE  DATE        AMOUNT
0   10218   WHF     PR      2/14/2020   -329.90
1   10218   WHF     PR      4/17/2020   -307.87
2   10218   WHF     PR      2/5/2021    -78.09
3   10218   WHF     PR      5/14/2021   -2.28
4   10218   WHF     AP      8/12/2021   -69.04
... ...     ...     ...     ...         ...
283 10200   WHP     AP      9/11/2023   -140.15
284 10200   WHP     AP      9/11/2023   -1173.61
285 10270   WCPS    AP      5/23/2024   -109.60
286 10270   WCPS    AP      5/29/2024   -154.54
287 10270   WCPS    AP      5/31/2024   -258.30

This is basically unreconciled items from our company bank accounts (obviously, sensitive info is gone)...PR is for payroll, AP = Accounts Payable, AR = Accounts Receivable, GL = General Ledger...DIV is our different divisions/companies, and each company may have multiple accounts. My main goal is to identify where we need to put our biggest efforts in figuring out what's happening with our money.
Here's what the heatmap looks like that was auto-generated, with minor tweaks from myself (my data was uploaded under variable 'df'):
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3.5))
plt.suptitle('# of Unreconciled Items as of 06/01/2024',fontweight='bold')
df_2dhist = pd.DataFrame({
    x_label: grp['SOURCE'].value_counts()
    for x_label, grp in df.groupby('DIV')
})
sns.heatmap(df_2dhist, cmap='viridis', annot=True, linewidth=.5, square=True)
plt.xlabel('')
_ = plt.ylabel('')


This heatmap is super helpful in identifying that we need to be looking at our AP team for our WCP/WCF companies and our Payroll team for the WHF/WHC companies (if I had to identify places to start). It's easy to see the counts are higher in these areas.
Ideally I'd like another heatmap with the sum of the amounts instead of counts. I'm not sure how to make that happen. For example, there may be an item under AR that's worth a LOT of money that hasn't hit our bank yet and I'd like to be able to identify that, even if there's only a count of 4 items total for AR.
In addition, I've also tried various other types of charts to show this data. For example, I'd like to be able to be able to group data by date (for example, maybe we want to see the items that are older than 3 months so that we know what's ageing and needs to be figured out).
I've tried creating a pivot table in Excel (that's my strong area, I'm very new to programing for data science) and then uploading that as a second document, but I know it's not going to give me all of the versatility I want.
Below is one failed attempt at working with my summarized data:
    DIV     SOURCE  AMT
0   WCDT    AP      -149109.52
1   WCDT    GL      -531.74
2   WCF     AP      -679550.20
3   WCF     AR      1216974.00
4   WCF     GL      -462.00
5   WCP     AP      -379343.06
6   WCP     AR      50814.65
7   WCP     GL      26060.74
8   WCP     PR      -969.95
9   WCPS    AP      -522.44
10  WCPS    GL      -694.72
11  WHC     AP      -420.03
12  WHC     PR      -8229.75
13  WHF     AP      -1188.54
14  WHF     PR      -2483.02
15  WHP     AP      -44147.38
16  WHP     GL      -122.60
17  WHP     PR      -11537.80

When I try to use the recommended plots, it shows all of my amounts as some combination of numbers between -2 to 2 (or similar). The amounts never show up as my actual summarized amounts that I'm looking for.

I've also tried building my own plots but I'm very new and it hasn't panned out thus far.
If anyone has any additional recommendations on what types of charts would look good and help us compare our data and identify our problem areas, please let me know!

Post your dataset as text and not screenshots of it. That way people can copy and paste it to reproduce it.

Welcome to SO! As recommended in [ask], please [edit] your post so as to share all code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images.
To share dataframes: copy-paste the output of e.g. print(df), print(df.head()) or print(df.to_dict()).

"another heatmap with the sum of the amounts instead of counts": suggesting to rework the data using pd.pivot_table as in Generating a Dynamic DataFrame from an Existing Dataset with aggfunc = np.sum instead of aggfunc = len

I have 2 suggestions for you:

The new heatmap chart can be something like this:

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3.5))
plt.suptitle('# of Unreconciled Items as of 06/01/2024',fontweight='bold')
df_2dhist = pd.DataFrame({
    x_label: grp.groupby('SOURCE').sum()['AMOUNT']
    for x_label, grp in df.groupby('DIV')
})
sns.heatmap(df_2dhist, cmap='viridis', annot=True, fmt='.1f', linewidth=.5, square=True)
plt.xlabel('')
_ = plt.ylabel('')


For this I'd like to be able to be able to group data by date (for example, maybe we want to see the items that are older than 3 months so that we know what's ageing and needs to be figured out), you can try this:

# Convert DATE to datetime
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# Calculate number of dates between today and each day in the dataset and insert the results in a new column
l = []
for d in df['DATE']:
    x = pd.Timedelta(pd.Timestamp.today() - d, unit='days')
    l.append(x)

df['Timedelta'] = pd.DataFrame(l)
df['Timedelta'] = df['Timedelta'].dt.days

# Apply the condition and visualize the items that are older than 3 months (90 days)
older_than_90_days = df['Timedelta'] > 90

df[older_than_90_days]\
.groupby(by=['DIV', 'SOURCE'])\
.agg({'AMOUNT':'sum'})

